# OptaPlanner: How to read game armor data from JSON and find optimal set of armor based on weight + stats?

Tags: constraints, mathematical-optimization, optaplanner

[Elden Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elden_Ring) is a hit game that has some interesting theorycrafting behind it.

There are hundreds of armor pieces, weapons, and spells. Finding optimal combinations of them based on player & item stats is an interesting practical problem.

I've always wanted to learn how to use Constraint Solvers and it seems a good usecase exists!

---

**Goal:**

- Given a list of all armor in the game in JSON format
- Find the **set of armor** (head, chest, legs, arms) that has:

  - The **highest POISE** and **PHYSICAL_DEFENSE**
  - For the **lowest WEIGHT**

---

Here is the repo:

- https://github.com/GavinRay97/elden-ring-optimizer-optaplanner

My attempt so far:

- [Put the armor data here](https://github.com/GavinRay97/elden-ring-optimizer-optaplanner/blob/master/src/main/resources/armor.json)
- [Created data class that matches JSON](https://github.com/GavinRay97/elden-ring-optimizer-optaplanner/blob/master/src/main/java/domain/ArmorPiece.java)
- [Created `@PlanningEntity` class for a combination of armor](https://github.com/GavinRay97/elden-ring-optimizer-optaplanner/blob/eeef6d91ace691a443b8f8301d31d13919d9ae93/src/main/java/domain/ArmorSet.java#L9-L41)
- [Created `@PlanningSolution` class (not sure if this is correct)](https://github.com/GavinRay97/elden-ring-optimizer-optaplanner/blob/eeef6d91ace691a443b8f8301d31d13919d9ae93/src/main/java/solver/ArmorSetComboPlanningSolution.java#L22-L61)
- [Tried to write Solver, doesn't work](https://github.com/GavinRay97/elden-ring-optimizer-optaplanner/blob/eeef6d91ace691a443b8f8301d31d13919d9ae93/src/main/java/solver/ArmorSetEasyOptimizer.java#L7-L52)

## Update

I managed to solve it after advice below

The trick was to change to use `PlanningEntityProperty`:

```java
@PlanningSolution
public class ArmorSetComboPlanningSolution {

    public List<ArmorPiece> armorPieces;
    public Map<Integer, List<ArmorPiece>> armorByType;

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "headRange")
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    public List<ArmorPiece> headList;

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "chestRange")
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    public List<ArmorPiece> chestList;

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "armsRange")
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    public List<ArmorPiece> armsList;

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "legsRange")
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    public List<ArmorPiece> legsList;

    @PlanningEntityProperty
    public ArmorSet armorSet;

    @PlanningScore(bendableHardLevelsSize = 1, bendableSoftLevelsSize = 5)
    BendableLongScore score;

    ArmorSetComboPlanningSolution() {
    }

    ArmorSetComboPlanningSolution(List<ArmorPiece> armorPieces) {
        this.armorPieces = armorPieces;
        this.armorByType = armorPieces.stream().collect(groupingBy(ArmorPiece::armorCategoryID));
        this.headList = armorByType.get(0);
        this.chestList = armorByType.get(1);
        this.armsList = armorByType.get(2);
        this.legsList = armorByType.get(3);
        // Need to initialize a starting value
        this.armorSet = new ArmorSet(0L, this.headList.get(0), this.chestList.get(0), this.armsList.get(0), this.legsList.get(0));
    }
}
```

Then the scorer:

```java
public class ArmorSetEasyOptimizer implements EasyScoreCalculator<ArmorSetComboPlanningSolution, BendableLongScore> {

    private final int TARGE_POISE = 61;
    private final double MAX_WEIGHT = 60.64;

    public ArmorSetEasyOptimizer() {
    }

    @Override
    public BendableLongScore calculateScore(ArmorSetComboPlanningSolution solution) {
        long hardScore = 0L;
        ArmorSet armorSet = solution.armorSet;

        if (armorSet.getTotalPoise() < TARGE_POISE) {
            hardScore--;
        }

        if (armorSet.getTotalWeight() > MAX_WEIGHT) {
            hardScore--;
        }

        long poiseRatio = (long) (armorSet.getTotalPoise() / (double) armorSet.getTotalWeight() * 100);

        long physicalDefenseScaled = (long) (armorSet.getTotalPhysicalDefense() * 100);
        long physicalDefenseToWeightRatio = (long) (physicalDefenseScaled / armorSet.getTotalWeight());

        long magicDefenseScaled = (long) (armorSet.getTotalMagicDefense() * 100);
        long magicDefenseToWeightRatio = (long) (magicDefenseScaled / armorSet.getTotalWeight());

        return BendableLongScore.of(
                new long[]{
                        hardScore
                },
                new long[]{
                        poiseRatio,
                        physicalDefenseScaled,
                        physicalDefenseToWeightRatio,
                        magicDefenseScaled,
                        magicDefenseToWeightRatio
                }
        );
    }
}
```

## Results

```java
19:02:12.707 [main] INFO org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase - Local Search phase (1) ended: time spent (10000), best score ([0]hard/[179/3540/97/2750/75]soft), score calculation speed (987500/sec), step total (4046).

19:02:12.709 [main] INFO org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver - Solving ended: time spent (10000), best score ([0]hard/[179/3540/97/2750/75]soft), score calculation speed (985624/sec), phase total (2), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE).

[0]hard/[179/3540/97/2750/75]soft

ArmorSet (Weight: 36.3, Poise: 65, Physical: 35.4, Phys/Weight: 0.97, Magic: 27.5, Magic/Weight: 0.75 ) [
    head: Radahn Soldier Helm (Weight: 4.0, Poise: 5),
    chest: Veteran's Armor (Weight: 18.9, Poise: 37),
    arms: Godskin Noble Bracelets (Weight: 1.7, Poise: 1),
    legs: Veteran's Greaves (Weight: 11.7, Poise: 22)
]
```

Comment: I did provide an answer, although I should perhaps point out that the question is missing. :-) What specifically is the problem, what does not work?

Comment: The scoring implementation must be wrong, the output of the solver is an empty list. Based on your other comment, it seems like I need to modify the scorer to look at just a single ArmorSet. I'm not entirely sure how to do this though

Comment: As you're filling out your PlanningSolution from your JSON file, make sure you generate one `ArmorSet` instance and store it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a strange problem, because you only need one planning entity instance. There only ever needs to be one `ArmorSet` object - and the solver will be assigning different armor pieces as it comes closer and closer to an optimal combination.

Therefore your easy score calculator doesn't ever need to do any looping. It simply takes the single `ArmorSet`'s weight and poise and creates a score out of it.

However, even though I think that this use case may be useful as a learning path towards constraint solvers, some sort of a brute force algorithm could work as well - your data set isn't too large. More importantly, with an exhaustive algorithm such as brute force, you're eventually guaranteed to reach the optimal solution.

(That said, if you want to enhance the problem with matching these armor sets to particular character traits, then it perhaps may be complex enough for brute force to become inadequate.)

On a personal note, I attempted Elden Ring and found it too hardcore for me. :-) I prefer games that guide you a bit more.

Comment: Oh wow, didn't expect to find an answer by you here! This is probably a silly question -- but how do I score this? I can't use hard/soft I think because I need to assign a value (probably the ratio), is there some kind of "FixedValueScore" I could use?

Comment: I got it! Used "BendableScore"

Comment: Looks like it should work. Just FYI - the way you have your score laid out means that you are saying that poiseRatio is more important than physicalDefenseScaled, and that in turn is more important than physicalDefenseToWeightRatio etc. If that's not the case, and you want all of these values to be treated equally, find a way to normalize these numbers and sum them up in a single score level.